# pandas.DateFrame.to_excel() method overwrite the EXCEL

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('trade_details.xlsx')

...

df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
```

I'm using `to_excel()` method to transform DataFrame into Excel, but it 
turns out `to_excel()` will overwrite the existing Excel instead add new rows in it, then I used `to_csv('trade_detail.csv', mode='a')` to gain that, I just wondering could `to_excel` do that? (like "mode='a'")